# Delete songs from iPhone but keep in iPod

Tags: iphone, itunes, mp3

I want to delete songs from iPhone but keep in iPod in iTunes. when uncheck songs from library, this erase from both devices. Is there a way to remove all the songs *just from iPhone?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two separate playlist, one for the iphone and one for the ipod.  Drag in the songs you want for each playlist and then just sync these playlists to the appropriate device.